# MySQL server not returning correct output

Tags: php

I have a table named `booktable` as shown in screenshot. When I run the query the output is `Table availabe` though it shoud be `Table not available.`
 Initially, I tried to check the condition without using `array_key_exists` and the solutions are mentioned below but none of them worked.

```
<?php
require 'dbconnect.php'; //connection to db is success

$search = "SELECT Table_list FROM booktable WHERE status='booked'";
$table_query = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$search);
$row_check = mysqli_num_rows($table_query);

if($row_check>=1){
    $tables = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($table_query)){
        $output = $row['Table_list'].'<br>';
        echo $tables[] = $output;  //returns o/p: Table1, Table2, Table3
        }
    if(array_key_exists('Table1',$tables)){ //trying to check if 'Table1' is in the array
        echo 'Table not available'; //if 'Table1' exists should echo this line
    }else{
        echo'Table available';
    }
}
?>
```

[image: table:booktable]

If I put `array_key_exists` part inside `while loop` the o/p would be same as not putting the statement inside the loop, i.e there is no change in o/p. 
 so, I tried to go with this approach but I'm not getting right o/p as before. What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: try it like that  if($output == 'Table1')

Comment: @ Kaushal shah still getting the same o/p, no change.

Comment: you are already querying with `status='booked'` that means all the table it returns are not available please explain more what are you trying to acheive.

Comment: @ Abhishek gurjar I'm trying to check the status of `Table1`,i.e, `booked` or `empty`. If it is `booked` then it should return `Table not available` & if it is `empty` then it should return `Table available`. But I'm getting `Table available` for the `booked` status.

Answer (score 1):

Your **$output** variable overwrite with last row value your last value is Table3 which is  != Table1

**REASON :** your while loop ends before if statement and last value store in $output variable

**Code :**

```
if ($row_check >= 1)
{
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($table_query))
      {
             $output = $row['Table_list'] ; 

            if ($output == 'Table1')
            {
                  echo $output .' Table not available <br>';
            }
            else
            {
                  echo $output .' Table available <br>';
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: I got it why I was getting the wrong result but I did what you mentioned but I'm still not getting the right o/p. Even if `$output == 'Table1'` where `$output=Table1`, I'm getting `Table available` but it should be `Table not available`. Can you plz explain why is this happening?

Comment: @007mrviper may be white space issue use trim or var_dump($output) before if statement and check what it is return

Comment: I tried using `if(trim($output) == 'Table1')` & `var_dump($output)=='Table1'` but there is no change in o/p. Also, I manually checked in db but there are no whitespaces.

Comment: just var_dump($output) and see what it return @007mrviper

Comment: I tried with both `trim` & `var_dump` one at a time but both time the result was same. If you have access to `MySQL` server can you mimic what i'm trying to achieve. The db doesn't have much data as can be seen in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong approach for what you're trying to do:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($table_query)){
        echo $output = $row['Table_list'].'<br>';
    }
    if($output==('Table1')){
        echo'Table not available';
    }else{
        echo'Table available';
    }
```

Because with `while` you run through all tables and only then you try to check. And in very strange way. In your case ,if i understood it correctly, full sentence should look like this:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($table_query)){
    $output = $row['Table_list'];
    echo $output.'<br>'.'Table not available';
}
```

This will print something like this:

```
Table1
Table not available 
Table2
Table not available 
Table3
Table not available
```

For only `Table1` it should look like this:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($table_query)){
   $output = $row['Table_list'];
   if($output == 'Table1'){
        echo $output.'<br>'.'Table not available';
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to check whether `Table1` is available or not. I don't want to display info about other tables. So, how can I achieve the result in correct way?

Comment: @007mrviper i have update my answer. Simply just check if it's `Table1`, but i suggest to modify your select to only take information about `Table1` if it's only necessary table for you

Comment: I edited my code & did it like you said but it doesn't display any result. If I add an `else` statement then it displays the info of `else` statement but the result(s) of `if` statement is not displayed. Same as previously encountered problem.

Comment: @007mrviper Strange behavior. Maybe `Table1` record in database has special character like `space` after & look something like this `Table1 `? You can try `if(trim($output) == 'Table1')` to check this case

Answer (score 1):

```
$tables = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($table_query)){
    $tables[] = $row['Table_list'].'<br>';//value stored: Table1, Table2, Table3
}

print_r($tables) //displays the stored data on '$tables', this line is optional
$a = print_r($tables[0]);
$b = print_r($tables[1]);
$c = print_r($tables[2]);

$tables1 = array($a,$b,$c);

if(in_array('Table1',$tables1)){
    echo 'Table not available';
}else{
    echo'Table available';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your code, use `in_array()`  instead of `array_key_exists()`

```
if(in_array('Table1',$tables))
```