# Re: MySQL server not returning correct output

Tags: php, mysql

I have similar problem as mentioned in this question: [MySQL server not returning correct output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783915/mysql-server-not-returning-correct-output) but the problem wasn't solved in that particular question even when the problem was changed a bit.

```
<?php
require 'dbconnect.php'; //connection to db is success

$search = "SELECT Table_list FROM booktable WHERE status='booked'";
$table_query = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$search);
$row_check = mysqli_num_rows($table_query);

if($row_check>=1){
    $tables = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($table_query)){
        $output = $row['Table_list'].'<br>';
        echo $tables[] = $output;  //returns o/p: Table1, Table2, Table3
        }
    if(array_key_exists('Table1',$tables)){ //trying to check if 'Table1' is in the array
        echo 'Table not available'; //if 'Table1' exists should echo this line
    }else{
        echo'Table available';
    }
}
?>
```

Table created in my db is here: [Table](https://photos.google.com/u/2/photo/AF1QipNX1LcgrCYkmPk7L-pSLasXLDOCvtanRrEzTSka)

From `while loop` 3 outputs are generated and via `array` method & `Table1` has to be compared with the outputs. If `Table1` is found in the `array`, it should echo `Table not available` but it is echoing `Table available`.
Why is the `array` not working?

Comment: Please print $tables and share the array ...

Comment: Table is linked to `Table` tag. I can't print images, rep of 10 is required.

Comment: `$tables[]` is creating an index for you, try `$tables[$table_id] = $output` then `array_key_exists` in this context should work for you, obviously adjusting `$table_id` as required

Comment: @Zanderwar Can you give an illustration with the code the above?

Answer (score 2):

> array_key_exists() returns TRUE if the given key is set in the array.
>   key can be any value possible for an array index.
>   I dont think you are checking key present in the array so the `array_key_exists` cannot be used here use `in_array()` instead of `array_key_exists`

```
$array  = array("table1","table2","tabl3");
if(in_array('table2',$array)){
  echo "Table not available";   
} else {
 echo "Table available";    
}
```

Comment: your method is `static method` but I want to create `dynamic method` for checking the `status` of table. In my que above, `$tables` should store 3 outputs that are generated through `while loop` and the string `Table` should be compared among the 3 outputs. How can I do this dynamically?

Comment: I don't check your whole code , you can see that if the array is not empty it will output as you wish .

Comment: You need to make some changes only in the array_key_exist() part I think it works perfectly otherwise

Comment: `$tables` was initialized as array but it is storing only last o/p, what can I do to to solve this?

Comment: I am not familiar with mysqli , so what happens when you echo $output

Comment: `$output` echoes `Table1, Table2, Table3` and I want to store these 3 outputs in `$tables` variable so that inside the `if` statement I can compare `Table1` with the values stored in `$tables`.

Comment: I have tested your code and it's working perfectly on my side if the $output variable is not empty then it will definitely create a table array